# Flask-Restx возвращается ошибка int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'

Tags: python, flask, rest

Имеется проект, на Flask + Flask_restx. Был следующий код :

```
get_calc_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()    
calc_parser.add_argument('postpress', required=False, default=[], location='json', action='append', type=list)
```

Все работало, возвращался ответ, но он меня не устраивал:

```
"postpress": [[1,2]],
```

Так как List заворачивался в другой List, и с этим было не удобно работать. Я изменил парсер, и вместо list стал принимать int:

```
calc_parser.add_argument('postpress', required=False, default=[], location='json', action='append', type=int)
```

Далее, при отправке через Postman запроса вида:

```
{
    "quantity": 99,
    "width": 297,
    "height": 210,
    "bleeds": 3,
    "chromaticity_front": 4,
    "chromaticity_back": 0,
    "material_id": 1,
    "postpress": [1,2],
    "template_id" : 1
}
```

Я получаю следующий ответ:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "postpress": "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'"
    },
    "message": "Input payload validation failed"
}
```

Мне понятно на что ругается response, но не понятно то, что я задал этот вопрос своему коллеге, и он прислал мне скриншот, что у него все работает с абсолютно идентичным кодом. При этом мы сверились и у нас одинаковые версии всех зависимостей. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем кроется секрет...

[image: Скрин коллеги]

Comment: На скрине я вижу `default=None` и `location` не указан. Это не те параметры, которые были указаны у вас. Попробуйте с этим поиграться.

Comment: Да, я забыл указать, что уже проверял это. Выставлял идентичные аргументы, от этого ничего не меняется. Единственное что, если не указывать location, и при этом отправлять на сервер json, он по умолчанию ожидает увидеть это в args, и выдает ошибку "не передан обязательный аргумент"